# Checking parameter validation using ToolRunner in Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, toolrunner

I have a hadoop tool that uses the **ToolRunner** and **GenericOptionsParser** to parse the **command-line** **arguments** and include them in Configuration (via `getConfig()`).

Since I'm not parsing these arguments manually and loading them into the Configuration using `config.addResource(path)` anymore, is there any (**clean**) way to check if the config listed in args matches the actual config in the directory? I don't see any helpful methods for it in **ToolRunner**, and **ToolRunner** uses **GenericOptionsParser** internally so there's no way for me to use methods from **GenericOptionsParser** to compare (which would only be somewhat helpful).